# Using a brush to apply 2 part epoxy resin without destroying it?

Tags: material-selection

I want to paint 2 part epoxy resin onto a 3D print to hide the layer lines.

Is it possible to do this without it destroying the brush that I'm using?

Comment: Epoxy won't necessarily stick very well, depending on what you're printing with

Comment: Two part epoxy is one of the most common smoothing agents for PLA prints.

Comment: Yes, it works quite well on PLA, but you didn't specify PLA. Also thin enough PLA gets rather fusible flexible which will stress the bike more than a more rigid part.

Comment: I'm asking about not wasting a brush, nothing else is part of the question.

Comment: When you Googled "clean epoxy resin from brushes", you found lots of recommendations from professionals, epoxy suppliers, and hobbyists. Was there something specific about those recommendations you're seeking clarification on?

Comment: When I Googled it, this StackOverflow question was the first result.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no.

You would have to rinse the epoxy out of the brush before it cures. The liquid components of epoxy are (as far as I know) all health and environmental hazards, so you'd need to dispose of the rinsing liquid as hazardous waste. And depending on the  liquid that can dissolve your type of resin and the kind of bristles your brush has, it's very questionable that it will survive the procedure and still be usable.

By far the simplest solution is to use a disposable brush, a stirring stick, a strip of cardboard or sturdy plastic or a piece of sponge or cloth grabbed in a pair of tweezers instead of a brush. As long as the resin is still liquid, the surface should smooth out regardless of whether you use a brush or something else. And once the epoxy starts curing enough to become sticky, it doesn't matter if you use or brush or not, it won't smooth out anymore.
After you're done, let the epoxy cure completely and dispose of the brush.

Side note: there are simpler methods of smoothing out a 3D print. Transparent nail polish achieves a similar effect but is removable after it's dried. Acetone vapor smoothing is a well-established method for ABS prints. And there's always the option of sanding / sand blasting.

Comment: This is a good time for "artist's" brushes sold for kids or house painters. It feels wasteful but working with epoxy often is. Industrially we looked at chemical means for removing part-cured epoxy, and there was nothing suitable for open bench work.